# Can anybody explain to me how to use Thunderbird's ability to use for vim?

Tags: email, thunderbird, vim, gvim

The only editor I can use with ease is Mutt.  It allows use of vim/gvim/ed/vi/nvi ...&c.  Most email these days requires that 
I use Thunderbird.  I've found articles that explain how-to use T'bird with vim/gvim. However, I don't quite understand the "magic commands" that let me configure this.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Thunderbird is a client for the open email standards (SMTP, POP, IMAP).. There are many other clients.

Comment: Providing private information like your email address in posts is against the policy of this site.